# How to set nzBreadcrumb translation or custom template

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have following code:

```
<nz-breadcrumb [nzAutoGenerate]="true"></nz-breadcrumb>
```

and added to my routes

```
{
  path: 'new', component: CompositeProductEditComponent,
  data: {
    breadcrumb: 'Create'
  }
}
```

now i want to somehow translate "Create", what i'am looking for is template like this:

```
<nz-breadcrumb [nzAutoGenerate]="true">
  <nz-breadcrumb-template>{{breadcrumb | transloco}}</nz-breadcrumb-template>
</nz-breadcrumb>
```

i am using "ng-zorro-antd 9.2.2"

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Андрей see https://ng.ant.design/components/breadcrumb/en#api - they added nzRouteLabelFn - you can pass es6 arrow function where you can provide custom logic for translating breadcrumbs